# How to choose the proper bounds for an Aggregate in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to follow the DDD *(Domain-Driven Design)* approach in my project. My domain is a barbershop and the use case that I want to implement is - book an appointment.

The problem that I have is how to correctly organize boundaries around my aggregate that should help to handle this use cases (book an appointment).

Let's say I have a barber. Barber has working days. Working day has working hours (e.g. 09:00 - 20:00), breaks, and other booked appointments.

Schematically it would look like this

```
Barber
 - WorkingDay
   - 09:00-20:00 <- working hours
   - Breaks
     - 13:00-14:00
     - 18:00-19:00
   - Appointments
     - 09:00-10:00
     - 12:00-13:00
 - WorkingDay
   ...
 - WorkingDay
   ...
```

Rules to be considered:

1. New appointment must not overlap existing breaks
2. New appointment must not overlap existing appointments
3. New appointment must be within working hours
4. Working day must exist
5. Working day must not be in the past

I have two ideas of how to implement this:

---

Create `WorkingDay` aggregate which will contain all related breaks and appointments.

Pros:

- All rules can be satisfied within `WorkingDay` aggregate
- Single `WorkingDayRepository` repository

Cons:

- Possibly large aggregate*

---

Create `WorkingDay`, `Break`, `Appointment` aggregates and verify rules in domain services

Pros:

- Small aggreages

Cons

- Multiple repositories (e.g. `WorkingDayRepository`, `BreakRepository`, `AppointmentRepository`)
- Business logic is split between aggregates/domain-services

What other option can be used? Or what approach to follow in my case?

Comment: How many barber in your system (one or more) ? Is there possibility that each barber has different working day , working hour and break times ?

Comment: One barbershop can have ~30 barbers. Each barber has a unique working day with breaks (also unique) and appointments (also unique). P.S. The minimum time for a break 5 min, for an appointment 15. It means that one working day can have around 100 child entities. (24 hours / 15 min = 96 appointments)

Comment: I am not expert in DDD but looking at domain and explanation BarberDay ( uniquely identify by Barber identification and Exact Day or Date) become agreegate root or say transaction boundary. By this you can have rule that must satisfy the variant of Barberday.

Comment: Yves Reynhout frequently talks about applying domain driven design to appointment scheduling in healthcare; start with "Evolving a Model" -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7StN-vNjRSw

Comment: I'd try `Schedule` aggregate possibly. Schedule should always be valid. Schedule consists of appointments with dates and rules around correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model this by using the concept of a `Schedule`. Schedule is your worker's workdays (or calendar) with appointments. It could be a decent aggregate - schedule has to be always valid.

Then you could have `AddAppointment` method on the `Schedule` which will check the invariants.

If you need to track changes, I'd suggest using Domain Events that could be fired and then logged.

To avoid concurrency problems with bookings, i.e. when 2 users are trying to book the same slot, you can:

1. Organise the DB in the way that it will not be possible to double-book, ie in your `bookings` table you will have a unique constraint on `<time slot id>, <barber id>` and when the second user is trying to book (insert a booking into the table) they will fail with unique constraint violation. Not sure how your db is structured but hope you get the idea.
2. use DB transactions. Both will try and update the row with time slot, only one should succeed.
3. put booking requests for the same barber into a queue.

Comment: Currently, I have `ScheduleAggregate` which contains `Breaks` and `Appointments`. Where `Break` and `Appointment` are entities.  Advantages of this solution that my `ScheduleAggregate` has methods like `book/decline_appointment`, `add/remove_break`, `change_working_hours`, `remove_working_day`. All of them play well together. The only problem is change tracking (I don't use any 3rd party tools) and concurrency. Where multiple users want to book an appointment. Some of them can possibly fail due to occupied time slot by another user.

Comment: some of the users failing to book a slot is not an issue, is it? it just need to be handled. I updated my answer with some more thoughts